# how to make url using plugin jurlp?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using  this plugin 
https://github.com/tombonner/jurlp.

I want to make url using parameter .can we make using this plugin.

```
here is my code
// first case
  var a='http://abc/deappsl/index.html?word=abc';
var abc={
  test:"lo"
}
// second case
  var a='http://abc/deappsl/index.html';
var abc={
  test:"lo",
  p:'er'
}

// expected output
//first
//http://abc/deappsl/index.html?word=abc&test=lo

//second
//http://abc/deappsl/index.html?test=lo&p=er
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IEnUPyGAgCCCPeII0xh3?p=preview
I have two cases

- First In url I have already "?" and add param it give expected result using "&"
- second if url does not contain "?" then it add param with "?" and "&"

can we use this plugin to make url ?
any update ?

can we make url using this plugin ?

Comment: The plugin work as expect. So what's the problem ? [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DV0h6fjmyQQvd3dT4NQH?p=preview)

Comment: got the solution thanks for help